# Customize no access error message

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I am using Joomla 3.x and have restricted access of some articles to certain user groups. When I am not logged in I get a really ugly message "You are not authorized to view this resource".

I would like that the user sees instead a custom message and a login screen, you know the basic "Thank you for your interest in …………… please register or login" message. Is it possible to change this in the code of joomla or is there even a addon which can do that?

NOTE: My joomla cms has a german language extension which is used in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

To get friendlier error messages you need to make some additions to your template.

> Joomla! uses the templates/system/error.php file to handle several HTTP Status errors, including "403 Forbidden", "404 Not Found", and "500 Internal Server" errors.

More infos are on the page [Custom error pages](http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages)

Hope this works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a language over ride (there is a tab in the language manager) to provide your own strings.